# MissingManifestResourceException with Silverlight application referencing resx files in other project

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, resx

I'm having difficulty getting a Silverlight application working.  The project is quite large, and was recently handed to me.  It consists of (among other things):

- A class library containing resources (let's call this `MyResources`).  This contains a number of .resx files that contain translated strings for various labels/text in the app.
- A Silverlight class library that links to all the resource files in the regular class library. (let's call this project `MyResourcesSilverlight`)
- A Silverlight app that references `MyResourcesSilverlight`

From what I understand, with Silverlight you can't directly reference a regular .Net assembly because of security concerns.  This makes sense, and explains the two nearly identical projects - the Silverlight class library and the regular class library.  (There's a bunch of other projects that use the regular class library).

The problem I'm having is when I'm attempting to run the Silverlight app, it is failing to load any of the localized strings, and I'm getting the following error message:

> > Uncaught Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
> >     Code: 4004
> >     Category: ManagedRuntimeError
> >     Message: System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "MyResources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "MyResourcesSilverlight" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

From the error message, it would appear that it is having difficulty pulling in the resource files - and this is also apparent from the missing text on buttons, labels, etc.

To fix this, I've tried doing the following:

- Cleaning/rebuilding the solution.  This had no effect.
- Right clicking on the resource files and selecting "Run Custom Tool".  The Custom Tool for all the resource files is set to `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`.  This has no effect as well, other than regenerating the code, which causes the class constructor to be internal (despite being set to public.  Another problem for another day - or from what I've seen - a known issue that Microsoft is refusing to fix).
- Setting all the resource files to `Embedded Resource`.  This had no effect.

I've been looking around at other people who have had this similar issue, and have tried pretty much anything I can get my hands on, but nothing seems to work.  Either I get the error message above, or I get an error message like `The name 'MyResources' does not exist in the current context.`.

If it helps to know, the project was originally a Visual Studio 2010 project, but I've converted it to be a Visual Studio 2012 project.  To the best of my knowledge, nothing has changed namespaces, which is a common cause of this problem.

Can anyone shed some light on what might be happening here?  I'm quite stumped.

EDIT:

Perhaps also worth noting: I'm not seeing any sort of text on any of the forms in the Visual Studio designer.  When I mouse over the supposedly missing StaticResource, it says "The resource ___ could not be resolved.".  I suspect this may be an indication of a larger problem with the resource files in general.  Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got this sorted out, but I'm still not 100% sure on what I did to fix it.  This is what I did, though:

Because of the odd layout with the two library projects, whenever I would touch the MyResources project, it would automatically update the MyResourcesSilverlight project.  This meant that if I did the "Run Custom Tool" on MyResources, it would regenerate the resource designer files with a namespace of MyResources.  If I then went into the MyResourcesSilverlight project and did the "Run Custom Tool" on the resources there, it would then rebuild the files with the MyResourcesSilverlight namespace.

When I started digging through the XAML files that were having issues, I noticed that they were referring to things like so:

```
xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:MyResources.Resouce;assembly=MyResourcesSilverlight"
```

This made me look twice at the namespace in the files being generated inside the MyResourcesSilverlight project.  Sure enough, when doing the "Run Custom Tool" on the resource files, it was generating them in the MyResourcesSilverlight namespace rather than the MyResources namespace.  I set the default namespace on the MyResourcesSilverlight project to MyResources, then did the "Run Custom Tool" again to regenerate the auto-generated code.  Despite manually setting the auto-generated code to create things as public, I still had to manually go in and switch the class constructor from internal to public.  Once I did that, things seemed to start working.

So if I were to sum this up, I'd say look at the following:

- Verify the namespace that your XAML files are using and the namespace of the auto-generated code in the resource files.  They should match.
- Verify that the constructor of the auto-generated code is public.  Don't trust the Custom Tool.

Hopefully this helps out anyone else who might be stuck on a similar issue.